# python get part of file name

Tags: python

I have a file name:

```
filename = 'Review Report - 2020-3.2021081716552'
```

Now I used 2 lines of code to just pick '2020-3'.  '2020-3' is dynamic, it can be another value.

```
report_name, ext = os.path.basename(filename).split(".")

a, b = report_name.split(" - ")
```

b will be equal to '2020-3'.

Can I just use 1 line of code to get '2020-3'?

Comment: While you probably *can* make this one line of code, I encourage you to keep it as two lines. One line of code that does lots of things is incredibly difficult to read and debug. Taking small steps on each line of code make it much easier to read and make changes to later when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Use Maxsplit:
One Liner:

```
date = filename.split(".")[0].split(" - ",maxsplit=1)[1]
```

Using one Liner is not recommended in Development of Projects, I recommend you to use the following:

```
filename = 'Review Report - 2020-3.2021081716552'
report_name, ext = filename.split(".")
a, b = report_name.split(" - ",maxsplit=1)

print(b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
2020-3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` function returns a list, so you can use the indices to get the respective string instead of declaring two variables to hold the values.

```
import os

filename = 'Review Report - 2020-3.2021081716552'

the_thing_you_want = os.path.basename(filename).split(".")[0].split(" - ")[1]

print(the_thing_you_want)
```

It will return `2020-3`.